# Simple Debug and Logging using System.Diagnostics

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I wish to be able to write entries to a console application which will describe when actions have been completed, possibly writing them to a .txt file at one point.

I would like it to be used with a separate GUI application running at the same time so i can use the application and monitor the log simultaneously.

I only assume the Diagnostic class is the right tool to use however I have never used any logging methods before, so i welcome any other suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at System.Diagnostics.Trace.  You can add different TraceListeners to it, including listeners for the Console or files.  Then replace all your Console.Write()/Console.WriteLine() calls with Trace.Write()/Trace.WriteLine() and you're good.  You can even implement your own TraceListener (it's very easy) to send the messages to your GUI app.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the System.Diagnostics.Debug to do tracing that is only enabled when performing a debug compilation (technically whenever the DEBUG compiler constant is set).

Comment: Thankyou Joel, is there any particular place that i can find out more on how to use it? Something as simple as a basic tutorial would be great.

Comment: It's hardly worth the trouble: it really is just changing Console.Write() to Trace.Write(), and maybe add a system.diagnostics using reference.

Comment: There are examples of using System.Diagnostics here: http://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Examples and also here http://www.thejoyofcode.com/From_zero_to_logging_with_System_Diagnostics_in_15_minutes.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The $0.25 solution is Project + Properties, Application tab, Output type = Console Application.  Now you've got a console window as well as your regular UI.  Anything you write with Console.WriteLine() will end up on that console window.

Comment: Would i need to do this if i follow Joel Coehoorn's solution?

Comment: Joel's suggestion appears to be to trace to a file, not a console.

Comment: The console would be something i need to be visible, is it possible to combine both yours and Joel's methods together?

Comment: You'll have to make up your mind about what you want.  Mine was $0.25, anything you write with Console.WriteLine() will be visible in the console window.  If you want to use Joel's $1.00 solution, you'll have to setup the Trace class in your app.exe.config file to also trace to the console.  Ask Joel if anything about that was unclear.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the help nobugz, i'll mark your answer up one vote but im sure you can understand me in giving Joel the answer to my question.

Comment: Hmya, such is the price of a cheap solution.  The right one was silky's btw.

Comment: But for my particular use i did not want to use additional third party extensions, although i will consider using it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from SysInternals to capture debug output. This is a separate GUI application that captures trace /debug output.

This post, [Using DebugView and C#,](http://www.cumps.be/using-debugview-and-c/) shows an example.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start using [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) as soon as possible; it's fairly trivial to use (though setting up is slightly complex, you need to make a few config entries), and it can be quite a beautiful system.

Comment: Why not compare/contrast this recommendation with the asker's consideration of using System.Diagnostics.  For one, you get System.Diagnostics for free; log4net is a separate assembly. Also, because it's part of the BCL, chances are more .NET devs know how to use System.Diagnostics which could benefit project maintenance.

Comment: gWiz: You're free to do that in your own answer :) Personally I don't see the point; there is no doubt, in my mind, that the best approach is to go for log4net. Perhaps I could explain, in detail, why, but I leave that as an exercise that can be done with research :) Not everything needs to be hand-fed to people, and certainly, I don't have the patience to do it.

Comment: I use/used nlog but moved to Azure. Suddenly things weren't as simple since I had to re-think my file system logging and to log to a cloud storage solution which wasn't straight forward.  My view now? System diagnostics doesn't seem such a silly way forward after all.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my admittedly self-serving answer: use my [logging framework](http://dotnetlog.theobjectguy.com). Unlike some other logging frameworks, it's extremely easy to use and configure. It also has a very small footprint. In addition, it comes with a small application that you can use to view your logs in real-time. It sounds to me like it's everything you need.

Comment: That does sound very promising but there are other alternatives that are, above all, free.

Comment: not free: $5 non-commercial, $49 for a commerical/site license.