# Writing All Program events to log

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging

I want to write every event on the running(in production) application to log just like Visual Studio does when I run the application in the debug mode.

[image: Image attached]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Debug and Logging using System.Diagnostics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017750/simple-debug-and-logging-using-system-diagnostics)

Answer (score 1):

There's all sorts of functionality in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace. I think you're looking for the [`EventLogTraceListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx).

This can be configured via your config file or in code. Note the remarks section that warns about possibly needing admin rights to create the event log.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. But I don't want to write log like this Trace.WriteLine("Test output"); . I need something automatically write everything happens line by line like in  the image I have attached